# Orion use https in the provider url setting of the registration API?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

https can be used in the notification url setting of the subscription.
https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/security/index.html#https-notifications
However, I couldn't find in the documentation if https can be used in the provider url setting of the registration.

Please confirm if Orion officially permits the use of https in the provider url setting of the registration API.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that Orion would allow Context Providers using HTTPS endpoints the same way as with subscriptions, as the code is the same (i.e. the code to deal with outcoming requests is shared between notification logic and request forwarding logic).

Could you check and tell us if it works (as comment to this answer), please? :)

**EDIT:** the test cases included in [this PR](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/4041) assure that HTTPS CPrs are working.

Comment: It depends on your Context Provider :). In the case of using Orion as Context Provider, then you should use `-https`, `-key` and `-cert`, described [here](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/cli/index.html). The `httpsPrepare.sh` script in the Orion repository may help to create key and cert files. [It seems the comment to which I was answering this this comment has been removed...]

Comment: Answer has been edited to include new information (check EDIT mark above)